# How to get url of product full image with multistore?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, cache, product-images

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

// For each category do
foreach ($categories as $_category) {
    // Get products collection and add attributes to select
    $products = $_category->getProductCollection();

    // For each product do
    foreach ($products as $_product) {
       $storeId = 14;
       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
       $product->setStore($storeId);
       $product->load($_product->getId());
       if (is_object($product)) {
           $imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
           $urlIm = $imageObj->__toString();
           $imageUrl[] = $urlIm;
           var_dump($imageUrl);
           exit;
       }
    }
}
```

I tried to get url's of cached product full images for store 14, but always receiving url's for store 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation` class:

```
$storeId = 14;
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');

# Start environment emulation of the specified store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    var_dump($_product->getImageUrl());
}

# Stop environment emulation and restore original store
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

***Note:*** if you use flat tables, you'll **only** get image path of **enabled** products.

Source: http://inchoo.net/magento/emulate-store-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks sv3n, how could i put this data in json file? any code after or before foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```
$product->setStore($storeId);
```

to

```
$product->setStoreId($storeId);
```

Personally I would concatenate those lines into one:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId());
```

Also the line:

```
$imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```

should be using $product and not $_product  as $product is the one you have set the storeId for.

You could also try adding a store filter to the initial collection:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($storeId)->setOrder("entity_id","DESC")->addAttributeToSelect("name");
```

Comment: Thank's now when i try:
$_product->getStoreId() - receving 14, 
but cach url I receive for 0 strore:
$imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
$picUrl = $imageObj->__toString()

Comment: $imageObj = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');    is using $_product and not $product. I have added this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    $savedStoreId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $storeId = 14;
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
     /*** all my code for receive product data ****/
    // return to saved Store 
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($savedStoreId);
```

I have received correct data for selected store only when I change current store. In another case, I had not access to the data cached another store.

Comment: have added an example of using the store filter on the initial collection.