# How can i create event observer for getting product data in array after saving the product?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

As I want all product details in json array, so that i will display this in fronend. So i want all products data in json file and for that i am using event observer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store product data as JSON string you can use this:

1.) observe the event `catalog_product_save_after`

2.) create an observer with this code

```
public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($product->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thank you sv3n, I will use this json on product listing page.
but i want all products in that json file.As i did this with all categories

Comment: One file for ALL products or only products from current category? How about a cron job that builds your JSON file instead of using "product save" event? However, maybe this is useful ... https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/how-to-get-url-of-product-full-image-with-multistore/182702#182702. Just replace `$_product->getImageUrl()` with `getData()` and save it as array/JSON string.

Comment: From your comment at the other question ... before `foreach` add `$array = array()` and replace `var_dump` with `array[] = $product->getData()`. After `foreach` you can use `$jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);`

Comment: public function productDataToJson(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        // $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $array = array();
          foreach ($products as $_product) {
            //var_dump($_product->getData());
            array[] = $product->getData();
          }
          $jsonData = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array);
          file_put_contents("c_node.json", $jsonData);
    }

this gives me error

Comment: Should be OK. Does it work for you? You may want to exclude disabled/invisble products ...

Comment: gives me error on array[] line - > 'unexpected [ or ( '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61813/discussion-between-sushant-thorat-and-sv3n).